# A user is making death threats

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, post-ban, offensive

Got an account making death threats, they have had one post closed already but the latest one is still hanging around.

I would have thought one death threat would be enough to ban them, anyone with a hammer?

**The non-answer in question**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584544

> Why you delete my post,was i right about this dumb kid,I will find this kid and kill him by my own hand

Comment: Just raise 'offensive' flags.

Comment: @Stijn per my reading, stuff like that is somewhat above regular [meta-tag:offensive]

Comment: @gnat sure, but it puts it on the moderators' radar. [Anything consistently flagged by our community members will be investigated, and we will always follow up.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

Comment: @Stijn yup, my point is that while for regular offensive stuff I rather favor "individual" flagging, for cases like this invoking some [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601) to ensure "consistent flagging" feels fair

Comment: @gnat That was my concern there language was getting more and more threatening. My first action was to raise "offensive" flag on the post and comments.

Comment: @Lankymart: I find it useful to hang out in the Tavern. Even if you are not that active, it is a very fast way to get things done. Like this one.

Comment: @martijn-pieters Regarding [your edit comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/275403/3) - I did the flag it, the first was closed promptly but then they re-posted straight away, I tried to explain how tags can be mixed up but then they continued with their comments making threats and threatening myself.

Comment: I'll consider that for the future, thanks @PatrickHofman

Comment: He's been hammered. I'm sure the guy enjoyed his 30 minutes of fame ;-)

Comment: @Lankymart: yup, but it is still a matter for the moderators. Yes, the user was clearly off the rails and out of bounds, and at the very least in gross violation of the terms of service (if not the law). But the first post was already handled by a moderator, so they weren't far away.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I asked for them to be banned not have the original question closed. I've now wasted my time and effort on that answer which got 3 upvotes (which in classic asp tag is respectable).

Comment: @Lankymart: I understand. Although the question itself was very bad and didn't deserve to be here. It happens to me too, that questions get deleted. I think you don't have to worry about the rep (any more).

Comment: @PatrickHofman I could have improved it, the fact is it wasn't on hold that long. How was the OP supposed to have the opportunity to improve the question if it's closed so quickly? I don't worry about rep but I put a lot of effort into that answer and votes reflected that. I would like to reach 3K rep though so I can cast close votes, so I can't see how you can't worry about rep. Lost 30+ rep when that question was closed.

Comment: @Lankymart: I once lost 80 by removal of one question. Reputation isn't important. And as a matter of fact, I upvoted three decent answers of you, so you could say the damage is covered.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I appreciate that thx, but you didn't have to do that. I would still like to be able to get my answer back though, is that possible? I've tried wayback machine and google cache but first one doesn't have it (probably because it wasn't there that long) and Google cache is out of date.

Comment: @Lankymart: Sure http://pastebin.com/cyj2iUJ1.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman I owe you one!

Comment: Just spotted this - good (well, not good - but you know what I mean) to know it happens to others. Had a user threaten me via email every day for a few weeks. Wasn't nice...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think we leave the hammer to the mods. Such a person doesn't deserve to be here and you are right about flagging this. This is about the worst I have ever seen on SO.

A few from the [Tavern on the Meta chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) picked up your post and flagged it as offensive, so it is deleted now. I am sure the mods will intervene shortly.

---

And they did. [Bart](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2562832#2562832) ([Cerbus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275403/a-user-is-making-death-threats/275404#comment110673_275404) noted here) found that his account has been deleted (and probably there are some blocks in place to keep him from coming back).

Comment: Aaaand he's been hammered.

Comment: Na.. This isn't the worst.. Atleast this user didn't abuse families of people who posted a better answer. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: He surely threatens too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583947/oracleodbcoraora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended/26584544#comment41784931_26584544.