# How to deal with people making threats?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, offensive

I have encountered an unhelpful and arrogant user. First he tried to close my question. Then he got frustrated by not being able to do so because the question got answers.

He keeps being chatty in the comments, insists his unhelpful comment is relevant, and now he is making threats to me.

[image]

In particular:

> "Offend me again and see where it gets you.  Certainly no help."

[How to update a field in an array's subdocument contained in an array's subdocument in MongoDB using C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783794/how-to-update-a-field-in-an-arrays-subdocument-contained-in-an-arrays-subdocum)

I flagged his unhelpful and offensive comments appropriately but I feel he is trying to use his power yielding from high reputation to make some unfair steps.

How can one protect himself against personal vengeance and threats?

Comment: Flag and walk away.

Comment: Don't engage in an extended discussion - don't make it personal - that is **never** a good way to resolve any problems. Flag -> go -> if that doesn't work maybe try the chat feature to speak one-to-one.

Comment: I am not sure if any other comments have been deleted but the ones which are still there shouldn't really be taken too personal... I don't find them offensive really... It's you who is asking for help so you should respect someone trying to point you in the right direction even through comment section... he didn't call you arrogant just gave you a hint -> you are the one who started all this IMHO...

Comment: "I am tired so I will not answer your question, but I will now post a useless link and will come back tomorrow to close your question" - to me this is an arrogant unhelpful statement and expresses plans to use power to prevent me from getting a useful answer.

Comment: @vba4all: it never matters who started; that comment is not constructive and should never have been made.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah comment isn't the best but it gives clues.. comments are supposed to only be temporary so there is no need to worry much about them anyway...

Comment: All comments have been deleted in the meantime. Thank you for that. (thanks to @Flexo♦). I am still interested in getting answers regarding how to prevent users from using their power yielding from higher reputation

Comment: @vba4all: users are still expected to behave according to our code of conduct. Making threats in comments still goes against that code.

Comment: related: [A user is making death threats](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275403/a-user-is-making-death-threats)

Comment: In this case, the user wasn't making death threats @gnat :)

Comment: but he is not making threats - the way I understand he's comment is that he's not going to help you... that's it..

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion yeah that's why I didn't say it's a duplicate. Referred it to show that there _is_ a line in threats severity that may warrant _nuclear_ options

Comment: also that: *`"Offend me again and see where it gets you." – Neil Lunn`* seems to be missing a sentence after the dot. Can't remember what it was but something about not helping you...

Comment: Do you really think anyone would express something meaning "Offend me again and I will not help you"? :)) ...especially after being not helpful?

Comment: @canon - It *is* a threat. Albeit of a somewhat vague unspecified kind.

Comment: @canon - Though actually from vba4all's comment maybe the "threat" was something that was actually specified and mundane (like "I won't answer your questions"). See what you mean about context.

Comment: It's the internet and just words on the screen, get over it and move on with more important stuff.

Comment: Meh. Full context: `Please get a grip and realize when you are in the wrong. Offend me again and see where it gets you. Certainly no help` doesn't look like a pleasant conversation, but there's hardly a threat here. @canon http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:D1koQ7neXa4J:stackoverflow.com/questions/26783794/how-to-update-a-field-in-an-arrays-subdocument-contained-in-an-arrays-subdocum+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de

Comment: oh wait. let me [remember](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) something :D how to deal with it, don't you know? ;)

Comment: Now that there's some context to it: It looks like you both were in the wrong here @Marek. While that first comment wasn't the best way to approach the subject, sure, your response was a bit on the harsh side as well, which only escalated things. I really don't see an actual threat there, besides threatening not to help you, just an unpleasant disagreement. If you felt that the first comment from the other user was wrong, calling them "arrogant" was not the best approach to explaining it. Next time, try a more neutral approach (explain, no name calling) and you'll get better results.

Comment: The first comment certainly wasn't well put or helpful. They did include a link that they presumably believed answered your question, so we ought to assume, despite being rude, it was in good faith. Your reply just escalated the whole exchange however. As for the "threat", I think you are being a little touchy there. I don't *think* they meant it in the way you took it, but they would do well to not respond that way.

Comment: @MattBurland "..but they would do well to not respond that way."  Is that a threat? :P

Comment: @jmstoker: Damn, see how easy that is?

Comment: I understood the threat to mean they would refuse to help you on future questions. It seems like both of you are taking it too seriously.

Comment: What a joke. Do you all not have something better to do?

Comment: @Neil Lunn good that you came by. Do you care to honestly explain to all of us what you meant by "...and see where it gets you"?

Comment: @Marek No. Does my comment just not express my opinion and all of that in a nutshell? You blew everything all out of proportion yourself. Then saw fit to waste time here as well. I have no time for this forum exactly because of this content. Very simply, if you are rude then I have no wish to help and will avoid any contact in the future. End of Engagement. No need to reply, as I don't have the time on inclination to respond.

Comment: @canon not sure if you have noticed, but he tried to not help me to start with. He just promised to close a legitimate question, assumed it was a duplicate, but did not bother to find it, "because he was tired". That provoked my original not-so-nice reaction. The link he originally posted was not helpful. How can someone who is not helpful at all threaten to not help you? And why would they assume they are the only one around who can provide wisdom? As you can see also here, this is an arrogant person. SO is becoming an unpleasant place.

Comment: @Marek : SO should punish that idiot who was patronizing to you. I upvoted your thread my friend.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just flag any evidence of improper behavior and move on.

- Don't engage them at all.
- Don't say anything about flagging, or do anything else to give them any indication that you're paying any attention to them at all.
- Don't allow their behavior to interfere with getting what you came to get (or give) in regards to the site. You really need to ignore them.

The moderators (or us, the community team) will handle it. If it's *really* egregious, you can [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), or even [find one of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) in chat if you have the time.

Let us take it from there, you did your good for the deed by telling someone who is in a position to handle it about what happened.

Answer (score 11):

Well, this is somewhat a case of "someone is wrong on the Internet" ([mandatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/386/)).

Just flag it and walk away as Bart suggested. There is no need and no gain from extended discussion apart from both parties getting angry.

This is the Internet; nobody is going to hunt you down for a simple comment.
This is the Internet; you can't change people's decisions by arguing / fighting with them.

What you can do is just flag it, and get on with your life. There has been a lot of cases similar to yours and there are similar suggestions in those posts as well. You don't even need to open another post to cast their names to the community. That's what flags are for.

Comment: In this particular case, the user has 30K reputation, which gives him certain moderator rights. My question is mainly about what to do to protect against expressions of power based on reputation alone. His threat probably meant he plans to induce some kind of ban on me, or delete my posts or similar.

Comment: @Marek As a single user, he can't do any of that on his own. Worst he can do is downvote 2 or 3 of your posts before the serial voting reversal kicks in; and closevote/deletevote your posts - but closing requires 4 other 3k+ users and deleting 2 other 20k+ users who agree with him the post should be closed/deleted. Furthermore, deleting AFAIK only works if the post does not have a positive score. As long as your contributions are meeting the site's quality standards, you shouldn't have any problems with a single vengeful 20k+ user.

Comment: But then they'll keep on being wrong!

Comment: @Marek: I think you're being paranoid here. The exact wording of his threat about what you'll get for offending him is "Certainly no help". That's not much of a threat. Even if he's so arrogant that _he_ believes that withholding his help is the worst thing that could happen to anyone, you certainly don't believe that, so… who cares?

Comment: @Marek: Nonsense. The poster clearly stated that if you offended again you would simply not get any help. There was no threat of misuse of power, inducement of some kind of ban, post deletion, or any other such threat. If you're going to feel "threatened" because someone says "if you keep up that attitude, I'm not going to try to help you any longer", you probably shouldn't correspond with people on the internet.

Comment: On a second thought after reading the whole conversation, I think @Marek is in the wrong here. From what I see, he said he is tired and gave you a link to read the documentation and you responded that "i know about the positional operator" "nobody cares if you are tired". I think you are in the wrong in this situation. Especially after with the rude attitude, coming along here to call his name to the community.

Comment: I am facing some targeting comments form a specific user and i am really pissed off with that, but these lines are real gold `This is the Internet; nobody is going to hunt you down for a simple comment.
This is the Internet; you can't change people's decisions by arguing / fighting with them.` to how to deal with such people, is just don't give a damm

Answer (score 9):

The way to handle this wouldn't have been to argue, but to respond to his close vote (and not him) stating why your question should remain open.  Making a back and forth argument in comments wasn't constructive and the only threat made was that he would stop offering his (unhelpful) input.

This meta question is misleading (especially your choice to partially quote his "threat" to make it sound more menacing).  There was no threat and you were every bit as arrogant as he was.